# How to use Typescript to tag certain fields as Personally Identifiable Information, so they can be obfuscated in logging, etc

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript, if we imagine an entity like this:

```
interface Order {
  id: string;
  address: string;
}
```

Now I would like to design a system where we can process entities feeling confident that the `address` field won't leak by accident, e.g. if I were to log that entity. For example I can imagine a logger that runs all data-to-be-logged through an obfuscation function to strip away `address`. To make a stupid simple example:

```
function obfuscate(data:unknown) {
  if(isOrder(data) {
    data.address = "***"
  }
  ...
}
```

But that function isn't really maintainable as the number of entities and their respective PII fields increase, and it's not even correct because what happens if `data` is actually an entity that has an `Order` as its field?

```
interface Shipment {
  id: string;
  order: Order;
```

In this case logging a `shipment` should still not allow `order`'s address to leak.

I think ideally there'd be a predominantly data-driven way to tag fields as PII, letting low-level egress functions obfuscate without knowing the details of the individual pieces of data they process, but not sure how possible that is (*e.g. if a field could be tagged as PII then an obfuscation function could inspect each field for that tag without knowing the details of the data being obfuscated*).

But how would you approach this? Are there design-patterns you'd recommend? Maybe approaches other languages take that could inspire a Typescript-solution? Happy to hear various tradeoffs to understand this space better.

Comment: Not typescript, but this might help with the search: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sensitiveparameter.php

Comment: At this point maybe you should push the primitive values down one more level, have everything be wrapped in e.g. `type Protected<T> = { public?: boolean; value: T }`, then `interface Order { id: Protected<string>; address: Protected<string> }` and only serialise values where `public` is _explicitly_ `true`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has been asked a few times in different ways.

**Don't** attempt to log everything and then remove the bits you think are PII, you *will* miss some!

`log("error with shipment : {obsfucate(shipment)}")`

**Do** log specifically chosen information that you know isn't PII

`log("error with shipmentId : {shipment.Id}")`